Algebra question Berkeley contest - 2018
Here is the solution from Berkeley math tournament, I am not able to understand the third step how after subtraction do you get the step 4, if someone can help that will be great.


Please don't use images to explain your problem. Use Mathjax instead.

Also please don't use the abstract algebra tag when this is clearly not about abstract algebra.

The first displayed equation in the solution has the form
$$
\frac13 A + \frac14 B - \frac2{11} C = \frac{53}{132}.
$$
The second can be rewritten
$$
\frac13 1 + \frac14 1 - \frac2{11} 1 = 0.
$$
Subtracting gives you
$$
\frac13 (1-A) + \frac14 (1-B) - \frac2{11} (1-C) = -\frac{53}{132}.
$$
But $1-A$ is just $$
\frac{y^2-9}{y^2 - 9} - \frac{y^2-4}{y^2 - 9} = \frac{5}{y^2 - 9}.
$$
and similarly for $B$ and $C$. That gives me
$$
\frac13 \frac{5}{y^2-9} + \frac{1}{4}\frac9 {y^2-25} - \frac2{11} \frac{13}{y^2-49} = -\frac{53}{132}.
$$
That seems really weird, so I used the eventual conclusion that $y^2 = 19$ to check the first displayed equation, i.e., we should have
$$
\frac13 \frac{19-4}{19-9} + \frac14\frac{19-16}{19-25} - \frac{2}{11}\frac{19-36}{19-49} = \frac{53}{132}.
$$
Matlab tells me that number is in fact approximately 0.2720.
On the other hand, $y^2 = 19$ is a solution of the third displayed equation. That means that the second and third equations cannot be equivalent, i.e., someone performed the subtraction wrong.
I suspect that there's a good and correct question hiding in there somewhere, but that someone made a typo or something.
Oh, well. You can't believe everything you read.

I was worried that i may make a wrong judgment if i dont understand the steps, yes i can confidently say that it is a typo

Note that the "to check the first displayed equation" should have RHS of 53/132 and not 0. (This is still not approx 0.272) $\quad$ Based on what I've seen from similar problems, they did the calculations wrongly. They wanted the coefficients (1/3, 1/4, -2/11) to cancel out to get the third equation. They should have used (1/5, 1/9, -2/13) instead.

Thanks, Calvin; I've edited to (I hope!) fix that glitch and its consequences. The algebra is, of course, still wrong. And Satish -- I'm really impressed that you and Calvin were able to do the puzzle archaeology and fit the shards together into something workable!
